# Octobercms select with ajax not working as expected

Tags: ajax, drop-down-menu, octobercms

I have the following code on a page:

PHP code section

```
function onSelecaoGE(){
$this['temp'] = post('selecaoge');
}
```

and on page html

```
<div class="col ptxt1">

    <select class="form-control"
            name="selecaoge"
            data-request="onSelecaoGE"
            data-request-update="_foe_rec_nivel: '#selnivel'"
            id="escolhage">
        <option disabled selected> -- Escolha um Grande Edifício --</option>
        {% for ge in ge_all %}
        {% if ge.era_id == 0 %}
        {% set conta = ge.recompensa_ge_conta2[0].count %}
        {% else %}
        {% set conta = ge.recompensa_ge_conta[0].count %}
        {% endif %}
        <option value="{{ ge.id }}">{{ ge.nome }} ({{ conta }})</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

</div>
<div class="col ptxt1" id="selnivel">
{% partial "_foe_rec_nivel" %}
</div>
```

and on partial just have

```
{{ temp }}
```

also i have jquery loaded and {% framework extras%} in layout file.

Everything looks good as per documentation and some examples i found.

But when i make any selection on the select it starts the ajax call, but it never ends.

After several changes i can't figure out what is wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

TIA

JL

Answer (score 0):

With the help of "alxy" on Slack we found that the problem is related with the version of jquery loaded. I'm loading jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js that appears to not have complete ajax support. I changed to load the regular version jquery-3.3.1.min.js and is working perfectly.

JL